# Get rid of NaN values and re-order columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have made an ad hoc example that you can run, to show you a dataframe similar to df3 that I have to use:

```
people1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13],['NaN',],['NaN',],['NaN',]]
people2 = [['NaN',],['NaN',],['NaN',],['Mark',20],['Jane',22],['Jack',23]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(people1,columns=['Name','Age'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(people2,columns=['Name','Age'])

people_list=[df1, df2]

df3 = pd.concat((people_list[0]['Name'], people_list[1]['Name']), axis=1)
df3
```

How would I modify the dataframe df3 to get rid of the NaN values and put the 2 columns one next to the other (I don't care about keeping the id's, I just want a clean dataframe with the 2 columns next to each other) ??

Answer (score 1):

you can drop nan values 1st:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.dropna(), df2.dropna()])
```

Output:

```
    Name   Age
0    Alex  10.0
1     Bob  12.0
2  Clarke  13.0
3    Mark  20.0
4    Jane  22.0
5    Jack  23.0
```

Or if you want to contact side-by-side:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.dropna().reset_index(drop=True), df2.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)], 1)
```

output:

```
     Name   Age  Name   Age
0    Alex  10.0  Mark  20.0
1     Bob  12.0  Jane  22.0
2  Clarke  13.0  Jack  23.0
```

If you just wanna concat the `name` column side-by-side:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)['Name'], df2.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)['Name']], 1)
```

output:

```
    Name  Name
0    Alex  Mark
1     Bob  Jane
2  Clarke  Jack
```

If you want to modify only df3 it can be done via `iloc` and `dropna`:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df3.iloc[:,0].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) , df3.iloc[:,1].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)],1)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Name
0    Alex  Mark
1     Bob  Jane
2  Clarke  Jack
```

Comment: I meant that you already have df3 as it is! (In the code I had to build a fake one just to obtain a dataframe example like the one I am facing). So, you cannot modify the way to build it, cause it is already like that!

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood correctly what you mean, this is a possible solution

```
people1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13],['NaN',],['NaN',],['NaN',]]
people2 = [['NaN',],['NaN',],['NaN',],['Mark',20],['Jane',22],['Jack',23]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(people1,columns=['Name1','Age']).dropna()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(people2,columns=['Name2','Age']).dropna().reset_index()

people_list=[df1, df2]

df3 = pd.concat((people_list[0]['Name1'], people_list[1]['Name2']), axis=1)
print(df3)

   Name1    Name2
0   Alex    Mark
1   Bob     Jane
2   Clarke  Jack
```

if you already have that dataframe:

```
count = df3.Name2.isna().sum()
df3.loc[:, 'Name2'] = df3.Name2.shift(-count)
df3 = df3.dropna()
print(df3)

    Name1   Name2
0   Alex    Mark
1   Bob     Jane
2   Clarke  Jack
```

Comment: Forget the code, I only made it up to get df3. Let's say you are given a dataframe like fd3, and you have to modify it to obtain one without NaN values and the two columns one next to each other. How would you do that?

Comment: the answer's second part is about that.

Comment: Right! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
people1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13],['NaN',],['NaN',],['NaN',]]
people2 = [['NaN',],['NaN',],['NaN',],['Mark',20],['Jane',22],['Jack',23]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(people1,columns=['Name','Age']).dropna()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(people2,columns=['Name','Age']).dropna()

df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

people_list=[df1, df2]

df3 = pd.concat((people_list[0]['Name'], people_list[1]['Name']), axis=1)
print(df3)
```

This will help you concatenate two df